# How to delete common lines from one of 2 files in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have 2 files, a small one and a big one. The small file is a subset of the big one.

For instance:

Small file:

```
solar:1000
alexey:2000
```

Big File:

```
andrey:1001
solar:1000
alexander:1003
alexey:2000
```

I want to delete all the lines from Big.txt which are also present in Small.txt. In other words, I want to delete the lines in Big file which are common to the small File.

So, I wrote a Perl Script as shown below:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($small, $big, $output) = @ARGV;

open(BIG, "<$big") || die("Couldn't read from the file: $big\n");
my @contents = <BIG>;
close (BIG);

open(SMALL, "<$small") || die ("Couldn't read from the file: $small\n");

while(<SMALL>)
{
    chomp $_;
    @contents = grep !/^\Q$_/, @contents;
}

close(SMALL);

open(OUTPUT, ">>$output") || die ("Couldn't open the file: $output\n");

print OUTPUT @contents;
close(OUTPUT);
```

However, this Perl Script does not delete the lines in Big.txt which are common to Small.txt

In this script, I first open the big file stream and copy the entire contents into the array, @contents. Then, I iterate over each entry in the small file and check for its presence in the bigger file. I filter the line from Big File and save it back into the array.

**I am not sure why this script does not work? Thanks**

Comment: If you want a non perl solution: `comm -1 -3 file1 file2 > file2`

Comment: @TLP - is that limited to GNU grep? And Also, shouldn't it include `-v` too?

Comment: @DVK You would have to ask someone else about that. Yes, `-v` to invert and probably `-x` to match entire line as ysth says too.

Comment: grep can do this, but needs more switches: `grep -F -v -x -f smallfile bigfile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script does NOT work because [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) uses `$_` and takes over (for the duration of `grep`) the old value of your `$_` from the loop (e.g. the variable `$_` you use in the regex is NOT the variable used for storing the loop value in the `while` block - they are named the same, but have different scopes).

Use a named variable instead (as a rule, NEVER use `$_` for any code longer than 1 line, precisely to avoid this type of bug):

```
while (my $line=<SMALL>) {
    chomp $line;
    @contents = grep !/^\Q$line/, @contents;
}
```

However, as Oleg pointed out, a more efficient solution is to read small file's lines into a hash and then process the big file ONCE, checking hash contents (I also improved the style a bit - feel free to study and use in the future, using lexical filehandle variables, 3-arg form of open and IO error printing via `$!`):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($small, $big, $output) = @ARGV;

use File::Slurp;
my @small = read_file($small);
my %small = map { ($_ => 1) } @small;

open(my $big, "<", $big) or die "Can not read $big: Error: $!\n";
open(my $output, ">", $output) or die "Can not write to $output: Error: $!\n";

while(my $line=<$big>) {
    chomp $line;
    next if $small{$line}; # Skip common
    print $output "$line\n";
}

close($big);
close($output);
```

Comment: The grep solution also needs an end anchor or more may be filtered out than desired: `/^\Q$line\E\n/`

Comment: @ysth - while not the main problem with the script, IMHO your comment is worth a separate answer

Comment: `..NEVER use $_ for any code longer than 1 line` -- sounds excessive. I would say as a general rule, do not use `$_` for more lines than your (boss's?) proficiency and memory allows. The different `$_` are not overwritten, they are just overshadowed, similar to `for local $_ (@foo) ..`

Comment: @TLP - you're correct, bad choice of words. It's "shifted out of scope" :)  And personally, when I'm reading code in a production emergency at 2am, I do NOT want to depend on proficiency or memory. I want it to be as crystal clear and obvious as possible. Meaning, self-documenting identifiers to the max.

Comment: @DVK Readability is good, I just think that `one line` as a rule of thumb is a bit extreme. But you are right in the sense that for the most extreme situations, extreme measures are prudent.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work for several reasons. First, lines in `@content` still have their newlines in. And second, when you `grep`, `$_` in `!/^\Q$_/` is set not to the last line from small file, but for each element of `@contents` array, effectively making it: for each element in list return everything except this element, leaving you with empty list at the end.

This isn't really the good way to do it - you're reading big file and then trying to reprocess it several times. First, read a small file and put every line in hash. Then read big file inside `while(<>)` loop, so you won't waste your memory reading it entirely. On each line, check if key [`exists`](http://p3rl.org/exists) in previously populated hash and if it does - go to [`next`](http://p3rl.org/next) iteration, otherwise print the line.

Comment: This is perfect. But his question was: why does his script not work? Despite your way being obviously much better, his should work too, no?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to implement it the way you suggested by using hashes as well. I knew there was a better way to implement, I was trying to do it quickly, but I will learn the way you suggested too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small and efficient solution to your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($small, $big, $output) = @ARGV;

my %diffx;

open my $bfh, "<", $big or die "Couldn't read from the file $big: $!\n";
# load big file's contents
my @big = <$bfh>;
chomp @big;
# build a lookup table, a structured table for big file
@diffx{@big} = ();
close $bfh or die "$!\n";

open my $sfh, "<", $small or die "Couldn't read from the file $small: $!\n";
my @small = <$sfh>;
chomp @small;
# delete the elements that exist in small file from the lookup table
delete @diffx{@small};
close $sfh;

# print join "\n", keys %diffx;

open my $ofh, ">", $output or die "Couldn't open the file $output for writing: $!\n";
# what is left is unique lines from big file
print $ofh join "\n", keys %diffx;  
close $ofh;

__END__
```

P.S. I learned this trick and many others from [Perl Cookbook, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003137).  Thanks